# Desktop Browser to Mobile Browser?

Tags: mobile, joomla, mobile-website

I already have a website with huge database which is good for Desktop browser my site is on Joomla base. Now i want to develop for Smartphone (like iphone, android, nokia) and mobile browsers. So how can i achieve this goal what is the best way of doing this.

Mobile Sites like Yahoo, Youtube i want to developed something like this because i'm new to developing mobile sites so any one can suggest me the right way for developing the mobile version for my current Desktop Site.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are extensions for Joomla that style your site for mobile usage here: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/mobile.

It makes sense to test your site using the emulators for iPhone, Android and Symbian at some stage before you release. Each software development kit includes the ability to use the mobile browser.

Note that this is *not the whole story*. You'll want to consider:

- Mobile users have much smaller displays. You'll need to rework your UI to take account of this.
- Mobile users have large fingers. You'll need to rework your buttons and links to take account of this.
- Mobile users tend to *consume* content rather than *create* it. Optimise accordingly.
- Searching for data with e.g. traditional search boxes is tricky; you may need to rework to use scrolling through lists.

Above all: test, test, test!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://www.mobilejoomla.com/